# how to implement google login in .net core without an entityframework provider

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am implementing Google login for my .net core site.

In this code

```
var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", redirectUrl);      
return new ChallengeResult("Google", properties);
```

I need a `signInManager` which is (by the code example) this:

```
private SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager;
```

I inject it via the constructor, and then I get this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager1[AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'AccountController'.

Googling learnt that I should include this

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();`
```

But that gives me this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore1[AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.AspNetUserManager1[AppUser]'.

And at that moment, I get the advice to add this:

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

But then I'm lost, because why does the `SignInManager` need a `IUserStore`, and should I add a 
`UserStore` and a `DBContext` and an `EntityFramework` store, when I will not be using that (for my Google login)?

So the question is: can I also do my Google login without the Entityframework store?

Comment: If you don't want to use Entity Framework then you have to custom storage provider:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity
In case you want to use Entity Framework but get some error ( as you described), you can reference my source demo: https://bitbucket.org/tuanv2t/net-core-demo/src/master/NetCoreDemo/GoogleLoginDemo/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not that I don't want to use EF (like I want to use some other provider), it's that I do not need a database provider because I want to use named (configurable in json file) users. So in the config file I have a list of 5 usernames, and with google login I want to allow them to login. In this case, I do not see any use for an EF provider, that's why I thought about not using it.

Comment: I also took a look at your bitbucket code and both the `app.UseIdentity(); and app.UseGoogleAuthentication` code lines were marked as obsolete.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If all you want to do is sign-in with Google, there's no need for `SignInManager`, `UserManager` or ASP.NET Core Identity itself. To achieve this, we first need to configure the Authentication services. Here's the relevant code for this, which I'll explain after:

**Startup.cs**

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultScheme = "Application";
        o.DefaultSignInScheme = "External";
    })
    .AddCookie("Application")
    .AddCookie("External")
    .AddGoogle(o =>
    {
        o.ClientId = ...;
        o.ClientSecret = ...;
    });
```

- The call to `AddAuthentication` configures a `DefaultScheme`, which ends up being used as both the *Application* scheme and the *Challenge* scheme. The *Application* scheme is used when attempting to authenticate the user (are they signed in?). The *Challenge* scheme is used when a user is *not* signed in but the application wants to provide the option to do so. I'll discuss the `DefaultSignInScheme` later.
- The two calls to `AddCookie` add cookie-based authentication schemes for both `Application` (our *Application* scheme) and `External` (our *SignIn* scheme). `AddCookie` can also take a second argument, that allows for configuration of e.g. the corresponding cookie's lifetime, etc.

With this in place, the challenge process will redirect the user over to `/Account/Login` (by default - this can be configured via the cookie authentication options too). Here's a controller implementation that handles the challenge process (again, I'll explain after):

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), new { returnUrl })
            });
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("External");

        if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
            return BadRequest(); // TODO: Handle this better.

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Application");

        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(authenticateResult.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email));

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            "Application",
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

Let's break this down into the two actions:

1. `Login`

   In order to arrive at the `Login` action, the user will have been *challenged*. This occurs when the user is not signed in using the `Application` scheme but is attempting to access a page protected by the `Authorize` attribute (or similar). Per your requirement, if the user is not signed in, we want to sign them in using Google. In order to achieve that, we issue a *new* challenge, this time for the `Google` scheme. We do so using a `ChallengeResult` that is configured with the `Google` scheme and a `RedirectUrl`, which is used for returning to our own application code once the Google sign-in process completes. As the code shows, we return to:
2. `LoginCallback`

   This is where the `DefaultSignInScheme` from our call to `AddAuthentication` becomes relevant. As part of the Google sign-in process completion, the `DefaultSignInScheme` is used for setting a cookie that contains a `ClaimsPrincipal` representing the user as returned from Google (this is all handled behind the scenes). The first line of code in `LoginCallback` grabs hold of this `ClaimsPrincipal` instance, which is wrapped up inside an `AuthenticateResult` that is first checked for success. If everything has been successful so far, we end up creating a new `ClaimsPrincipal` that contains whatever claims we need (taken from Google in this case) and then signing-in that `ClaimsPrincipal` using the `Application` scheme. Lastly, we redirect to the page that caused our first *challenge*.

In response to a couple of follow-up comments/questions in the comments below:

> Can I conclude that the `SignInManager` and `UserManager` are only used when using authentication with a database?

In some ways, yes, I think that's fair. Although it is possible to implement an in-memory store, it doesn't really make much sense with no persistence. However, the real reason not to use these classes in your situation is simply because you do not need a local user account for representing a user. That goes hand-in-hand with persistence, but it's worth making the distinction.

> And what very different code from what I read in the book (which I used for setting up my Google login) and all the other answers I've read.

The documentation and the books cover the most common use-case, whereby you *do* want to store local users that can be *linked* to external accounts such as Google, etc. If you look at the `SignInManager` source, you'll see that it's really just sitting on top of the kind of code I've shown above (e.g. [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs#L591) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/SignInManager.cs#L668)). Other code can be found in the Default UI (e.g. [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.2/src/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs#L121)) and in [`AddIdentity`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L45).

> I assume the LoginCallback gets called by Google. Does the HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync know how to check the data Google sends me? And as it's name is so generic, it looks like it knows how to do that for all external providers?

The call to `AuthenticateAsync` here doesn't know *anything* about Google - the Google-specific handling is configured by the call to `AddGoogle` off of `AddAuthentication` in `ConfigureServices`. After redirecting to Google for sign-in, we actually come back to `/signin-google` in our application. Again, this is handled thanks to the call to `AddGoogle`, but that code is really just issuing a cookie in the `External` scheme that stores the claims that came back from Google and then redirecting to our `LoginCallback` endpoint that we configured. If you add a call to `AddFacebook`, a `/sigin-facebook` endpoint will be configured to do something similar. The call to `AuthenticateAsync` is really just rehydrating a `ClaimsPrincipal` from the cookie that was created by e.g. the `/signin-google` endpoint, in order to retrieve the claims.

It's also worth noting that the Google/Facebook sign-in process is based on the [OAuth 2 protocol](https://oauth.net/2/), so it's kind of generic in itself. If you were to need support for more than just Google, you would just issue the challenge against the required scheme rather than hardcoding it to Google as I've done in the example. It's also possible to add additional properties to the challenge in order to be able to determine which provider was used when your `LoginCallback` endpoint is reached.

---

I've created a GitHub repository that contains a complete example that I built in order to write this answer [here](https://github.com/serpent5/SO53654020).

Comment: [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2) might be a useful follow-up read too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In case you are still using ASP.NET Core 2.2 (targeting full framework), be sure you use version 2.2.2 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, first i must say .. you have explained this beautifully! I'm a little doubtful about one statement tho, it says: `The Challenge scheme is used when a user is not signed in` please correct me if I've read it wrong, I think we can use the Challenge scheme (call  `ChallengeAsync()`) even when the given user is already signed-in (eg. to sign-in an already signed-in user with another scheme).