# Get authenticated email from Google

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using .net core 3.0 mvc need to get users authenticated email from Google and nothing more. Final result should be:

- User clicks the link to authenticate with Google
- Authenticates with Google
- Callback is called with user authenticated email

No user's database or user identity is needed just authenticated email.

Comment: I have read many examples but all of them suggest using VS to generate tons of code that I don't need + I am not using VS. This is simple task and I guess should involve several lines of code. Just can't find an example.

Comment: This is an answer that I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705039/625521